# How to change screen resolution and the size of items using command line/programmatically/batch or macro?

Tags: windows, batch-file, screen, resolution, magnification

I have a 3200x1800 screen. For daily use, I am at 3200x1800 at %200 window size. For gaming I usually drop to 1600x900 at %100 magnification. Can I write/find some kind of an automated tool which can switch between these modes. I am fine with writing a C/C++/C# program, and/or a batch file which can also log me out automatically, because you need to log out and in, in order the settings to take effect. I am on Win10 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[Display Changer II](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641) is the best software I can find. 
1) Copy *dc2.exe* to `system32\` folder.
2) `dc2.exe -dccmd.exe –listmonitors` return the current screen resolution along with refresh rate and monitor type.
3) `dc2.exe -width=1600 -height=900 -refresh=60 (more parameters can be added if desired)` (E.g: `dc2.exe -width=1600 -height=900 -refresh=60  cmd /c “C:\Program Files\text.txt”`)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a tool, that might can help you at least for a part:

http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/

Just call it like this

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1600 /h=900
```

It does not change the magnification however.

To accomplish this, the program uses the C++ function [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx). This might help you to get a step closer to your solution.